# How to remove vibration damper from a Volkswagen 1.8 TSI (EA888) Engine?

Tags: engine, vw, crankshaft-pulley

How do you remove the vibration damper from a **2010 Passat CC 1.8 TSI engine**? Which direction do you turn the bolt to remove it? **Clockwise** OR **counterclockwise**?

Comment: What year is your car?

Comment: 2010 Passat CC 1.8 TSI